# Why does "<input id='id' type=text name='id' value='H123'>" not get "POST"ed by FormData

Tags: post, input, ajaxform, form-data

When I submit the following form

```
<form name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id='id' type=text name='id' value='H123'>
<div class="file_browser">
<input type="file" name="multiple_files[]" id="_multiple_files" class="hide_broswe" multiple />
</div>
<div class="file_upload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="upload_button" />
</div>
</form>
```

The files[] get uploaded OK but input "#id" is not in the $_POST array.

I need it because I want to pass the name of the directory that the images are to be stored in.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are missing quotation marks around 'text' in

```
   <input id='id' type=text name='id' value='H123'>
```

Which should be:

```
   <input id='id' type='text' name='id' value='H123'>
```

Besides that I can't see any obvious reason why it shouldn't work.